# Can virtual machines be linked to my IP?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently created a virtual machine that can access the Internet using VirtualBox, and there is a website I have an account with that I would like to create another account on using the VM. I understand that the IP address of my host and guest OSes are different, but will the site operators be able to figure out through whatever information my VM provides them that both are run by the same person?

(And just to be clear, no, I am not trying to suggest any malicious activity.)

P.S. I realize that the title question may be poorly worded - feel free to let me know if you think I should change it somehow.

Comment: You're using the same external IP. They would be able to tell it's happening from the same origin (from they POV).

Comment: Your virtual machine also connects thru your host machine so, external IP won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM is using the same external IP as the guest operating system so it won't differ.

If you wish to change your external IP you will either need to go through a proxy, a VPN, or to reboot your router. (Even thouh it might not work instantly)